# My little test program that I got out of the Official MCTS EXAM 70-562 book is not firing the events

Tags: c#, asp.net, using

My little test program that I got out of the Official MCTS EXAM 70-562 book is not firing the events.  I followed through the computer logic in debug mode and it didn't even go into my events even though I have everything set up to handle them.  So the big question is what am **I** doing wrong?

```
    **CODE BEHIND FILE:**

    public partial class Calendar : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      Hashtable _scheduleData;

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        _scheduleData = GetSchedule();

        Calendar1.Caption = "Personal Schedule";
        Calendar1.FirstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday;
        Calendar1.NextPrevFormat = NextPrevFormat.ShortMonth;
        Calendar1.TitleFormat = TitleFormat.MonthYear;
        Calendar1.ShowGridLines = true;
        Calendar1.DayStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        Calendar1.DayStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
        Calendar1.DayStyle.Height = new Unit(75);
        Calendar1.DayStyle.Width = new Unit(100);
        Calendar1.OtherMonthDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
        Calendar1.TodaysDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 1);
        Calendar1.VisibleDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
     }

     private Hashtable GetSchedule()
     {
       Hashtable schedule = new Hashtable();

       schedule["2/9/2009"] = "Vactican Day";
       schedule["2/18/2009"]="Budget planning meeting @ 3:00pm";
       schedule["2/24/2009"]="Dinner plans with friends @ 7:00pm";
       schedule["2/27/2009"]="Travel Day";
       schedule["3/5/2009"]="Conf call @ 1:00pm";
       schedule["3/10/2009"]="Meet with art director for lunch";
       schedule["3/27/2009"]="Vacation Day";

       return schedule;
   }

   protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       LabelAction.Text = "Selection changed to: " +       Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
   }

   protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       LabelAction.Text = "Month changed to : " + e.NewDate.ToShortDateString();
   }

   protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
   {
     if (_scheduleData[e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()] != null)
     {
         //Literal lit = new Literal();
         lit.Text = "<br />";
         e.Cell.Controls.Add(lit);

         //Label lbl = new Label ();
         lbl.Text = (string)_scheduleData[e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()];
         lbl.Font.Size=new FontUnit (FontSize.Small);
         e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
     }
   }   
 }


    **ASPX CODE:**

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Calendar.aspx.cs" Inherits="Calendar" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">    
          <div style="height: 350px">   
             <br />
             <asp:Label ID="LabelAction" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label> 
             <br />
             <asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
             <br />
             <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label> 
             <br />        
             <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"
                OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"
                OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged"
                OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth">  </asp:Calendar>
             <br />        
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>      
             <br />      
          </div>
       </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Lorenzo.  I had been "casually" trying to figure out how to accept answers and vote up comments.  Your link to the FAQ's page helped me to do that.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoEvent wireup is not happening because you have not linked your methods of .cs file to the control on the .aspx page

Change your code to fillowing in aspx page source:

```
       <asp:Calendar  ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
        ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" 
        onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" 
        onvisiblemonthchanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: Okay man, when I try to link the csharp methods to the .aspx page as recommended I get the following error message:               Server Error in '/WebSite2' Application.
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.

Comment: I think you made some new mistake then, can you please post your new .aspx page code and codebehind file again, (As an edit to your question).

Comment: I just posted the whole .aspx and csharp code behind files.  Thanks for your help.  While doing some research online I have noted that (obviously) there is additional work involved in binding the calendar events to their event handlers. . . I just haven't exactly figured how to do it yet. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Mike your code seems correct, i myself tried running your portion of code and it worked here. Try looking at the events tab (click on thunder icon) in properties window and see are events bound to respective methods.

Comment: Thanks Shekhar_Pro.  I will keep "goofing" around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Where is _scheduleData defined in your code that you posted?

Comment: I doubt that's the issue - it's more 'why isn't autoeventwireup working? He's just shown us the code for his events.

Comment: Hashtable _scheduleData; It's set up at the beginning on the code behind file.

Comment: Please use comments to ask questions.

Comment: @Brian he doesn't have enough rep to comment, though. But yes - Chuckie, once you hit 50 rep you should add comments like this to the question rather than as answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your .aspx file make the following change to how you declare a calendar

What your doing is adding the

onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" to the calendar declaration. Save and rebuilt the application so that the next time you chose a date your code should  take you to the specific event.

I determined that something maybe missing from your code by adding a new calendar control and seeing what code it produced compared to what you type in from the book.

Comment: Okay. . . so. . . uhm. . . how exactly do i go about saving and rebuilding the application